# Soccer penalty shots

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Imagine a scenario where we have a soccer player who is shooting penalty shots. He makes his first shot with probability of failure $1/3$, then his second with probability of failure $1/5$ and so on, and at the $n$-th throw the probability of failure is $1/(2n+1)$.
>
> During practice, he shoots $19$ consecutive kicks. What is the probability he succeeds in an even number of kicks?

For each throw, the respective probability of success is $$1-\frac{1}{(2n+1)}= \frac{2n}{(2n+1)}$$

To find the total probability of success in an even number of throws, we must add the probability of $0$ successful shots, $2, 4, \cdots, 18$.

But the $2$ successful throws can be, for example, the $1$st and the $2$nd, or the $4$th and the $19$th. Then, obviously, we will multiply the $2$.
So how do we calculate the individual probabilities?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The probability generating function for the number of failures is

$$
f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^{19}\frac{2n+x}{2n+1}\;.
$$

The probability of getting an even number of failures is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{f(1)+f(-1)}2=\frac12\left(\prod_{n=1}^{19}\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}+\prod_{n=1}^{19}\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\frac1{39}\right)=\frac{20}{39}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Since the total number of kicks is odd, the probability of getting an even number of successes is

$$1-\frac{20}{39}=\frac{19}{39}\;.$$

Comment: @joriki: Many thanks! I thought it would be something simpler... Could you possibly explain a bit further about the generating function (what is x???) and also why the probability of getting an even number of successes is 1/2{f(1)+f(-1)}? Apologies but I am not very familiar with these topics!!

Comment: @CretonLaplace: Nothing to apologize for! It just seemed more efficient to first see whether you are and then explain if not, than to explain first, possibly without need :-). In a probability generating function $f(x)=\sum_kp_kx^k$ for the number of successes, the coefficient $p_k$ of the power $x^k$ is the probability for obtaining $k$ successes. $x$ is just a marker variable for the bookkeeping. The $n$-th kick contributes a factor $\frac{2n+x}{2n+1}$, since the probability of success is $\frac1{2n+1}$. (Multiply it out up to $n=2$ or $3$ and you'll see why this works.)

Comment: @CretonLaplace: The probability of getting an even number of successes is the sum of the coefficients $p_k$ for even $k$. This is the the average of the sum of the coefficients and the alternating sum of the coefficients. The sum of the coefficients is $f(1)$, and the alternating sum of the coefficients is $f(-1)$.

Comment: And, of course, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function. About it being something simpler -- I was surprised by the simple result! :-) There may well be a simpler way to derive it; this was just the first one that occurred to me.

Comment: It seems to me something must be wrong here. If $n=1$ then he will succeed in an even number of shots iff he fails at his first attempt. So $p_1=\frac13$. This does not agree with $\frac12(1+\frac13)$. I come to $p_{2n}=\frac{2n+1}{4n+1}$ and $p_{2n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{4n+3}$, so that $p_{19}=\frac{19}{39}$

Comment: @drhab: Ah yes, I took the probabilities of failures to be the probabilities of success -- thanks for spotting that -- I've fixed it.

Comment: @CretonLaplace: Please note the error that drhab spotted above and the corresponding correction to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Try to work out the recursive equality:

$$\left(2n+1\right)p_{n}=p_{n-1}+2n\left(1-p_{n-1}\right)$$

Where the probability that he succeeds in an even number of kicks by
taking $n$ penalties be denoted by $p_{n}$.

This is based on the thought that an even number can be achieved in two ways:

- an even number in the first $n-1$ efforts followed by a failure
- an odd number in the first $n-1$ efforts followed by a success.

Here $p_0=1$.